# API Validate route param with Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I faced with API problem in nuxt.js.

I'm fetching the data from an API with axios in the module of store `'category/'`. Everything works fine in case of fetching data. Event list is displaying and data flow through the store and component. I dispatched my asynchronous data from an API to the `mounted` property in a component.To be brief, I cannot validate my route params.

I want to return `true` on validating the proper url

```
export default {
validate({params}) {
return this.currentCategory.some((category) => category === params.category)

// Where this.currentCategory is the array of strings that have to match route params
// params.category is because my dynamic file called '_category.vue' in 'pages/'
```

I logged on template how this code behave.This validation returns `false`, but after a moment it returns true(because of fetching). I tried to add the condition `if(this.currentCategory.length > 1)`. I have tried a lot, but seriously I dont know what is happening there.

Comment: Could you add the code where you are calling `validate` from?

Comment: https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-validate/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found answer for my question

```
export default {
async validate({params}) {
const validateParam = await this.currentCategory.some((category) => category === params.category)

return validateParam
```